# Loop through scala dataframe putting values into variables for sparksql select

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table of table names and column names that I am returning as a data frame

```
val TablesToSelectFrom= spark.sql("select tablename, fieldone, fieldtwo from tableOfTables where current_date between start_date and end_date")
```

I would like to create a loop for each row that would have a spark.sql statement in it that would look something like this

```
val selectedFromTables= spark.sql("select  $fieldone, $fieldtwo from $tablename")
```

I will then export these new data frames. I have the export built but only when I hard code the table names. I would really like this to be table driven.

So far I have only found ways to print all of the rows such as

```
val rows: RDD[Row] = TablesToSelectFrom.rdd
rows.collect().foreach(println)
```

pseudo code would look something like this

```
val TablesToSelectFrom= spark.sql("select tablename, fieldone, fieldtwo from tableOfTables where current_date between start_date and end_date")

TablesToSelectFrom.foreach { row =>
val tablename = row.tablename
val fieldone  = row.fieldone
val fieldtwo  = row.fieldtwo

 val selectedFromTables= spark.sql("select  $fieldone, $fieldtwo from $tablename")

//or without setting to variables

  val selectedFromTables= spark.sql("select  row.fieldone, row.fieldtwo from row.tablename")

selectedFromTables.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header", "true").csv("/user/username/data")
}
```

I know the pseudo code is not correct just hoping it shows better what I am trying to do.

Comment: How many tables you have to select? That is what is the size of TablesToSelectFrom? Is it huge or small? As the above pseudo-code nested Dataframe operation is not allowed by Spark. You have to collect TablesToSelectFrom as Array/List.

Comment: @hagarwal it's small about 5 tables but they could change that is why I would like it to be table driven. It is .collect() to get the dataframe as an array?

Comment: yes .collect() will return the entries of DataFrame as array. Since tables size are small you could do collect() operation & then proceed on it.